# Is it possible to specify a npm module version without updating package.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I would like to override a npm module's version without changing the `package.json` file as I would like to avoid forking the repo, if possible.

If the `package.json` file looks something like

```
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "iwanttooverridethis": "2.5.0",
        ...
```

can I run a step like `npm install --override "iwanttooverridethis=3.0.0"` which would install version 3.0.0 of `iwanttooverridethis` instead of version 2.5.0? Or achieve the same result some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `--no-save` flag to install the specified npm package version without changing the `package.json` file. Just keep in mind that this is temporary and will reset to the one specified in the `package.json` file when you run `npm install`. An example is `npm install yourpackage@3.0.0 --no-save`.

Comment: If I run `npm install` first, and then `install yourpackage@3.0.0 --no-save`, will it replace the old version of `yourpackage`?